# How LEFT JOIN should return value though the main record is null?

Tags: mysql

My SQL Query is like:

```
SELECT SUM(i.itemPrice) as total, t.sTax 
FROM items AS i 
LEFT JOIN tax_table AS t ON t.branchID = 10 
WHERE i.orderID = 10
```

When `total` is not `NULL` for **`orderID 10`** it will return `sTax` Value. If the `total` is `NULL` for **`orderID 10`** the `sTax` is `NULL`.

How do I get `sTax` though if `total` is `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(i.itemPrice) AS total 
     ,CASE
        WHEN SUM(i.itemPrice) IS NULL THEN (SELECT t.sTax
                                            FROM tax_table AS t
                                            WHERE t.branchID = 10
                                            LIMIT 1)
        ELSE NULL
       END AS tax
FROM items AS i
WHERE i.orderID = 10
GROUP BY i.orderID
```

The query returns the total price of every items and if this total is `NULL`, the tax is returned (otherwise the tax is `NULL`).

Hope this will help.